# parallel execution freezes service

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a problem understand how Workflow Scheduler works, my architecture is the follow: I have several operations that call asyncronously a service from UI, it inizialize a new WorkflowApplication and calls Run() method, than it take some time to accomplish the operation, it goes through some steps and than an activity does the big work

I understand the workflow scheduler can process one workflow instance at time, **but while workflows are running that seems to "freeze" my entire website**, I can't access any other service, it become slow until all workflows finish. (I have also tried to call service just once and start all workflow inside it but the behavior is pretty the same)

Could someone help me understand that? There is some way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First impression is that there is thread starvation, or something similar with another resource contention, going on.

Are you using a WorkflowApplication or a WorkflowServiceHost to execute your workflow? I believe the first but it isn't quite clear in your question.

If you are using a WorkflowApplication: Are you setting the SynchronisationContext and are you waiting for the workflow to complete before finishing the request?

How many workflows are you starting and approximation how many ASP.NET requests are there being executed?

Comment: Yes I'm using WorkflowApplication and I don't Synchronize context, but I'm gonna try! I don't understand what you mean with "finishg the request", teorically the ui call the service, it create a workflowapplication and start it with Run() than it return a value immediatelly, while the wf is still running... this could happen like 1000 request by the ui at time

Comment: I've tried to set SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current to WorkflowApplication before to start it but it doesn't change. I noticed that if I declare static my workflow and reutilize it, it goes fast but I had several other error executing activities

Comment: With 1000 workflow instances running in addition to ASP.NET requests I am pretty sure you are suffering from thread starvation issues.You will need to re-architect so not all workflows will start running at once. I would suggest using a workflow service and the WorkflowServiceHost as that will let you use the WCF throtteling settings.

Comment: With that much concurrent work going on you may want to dispatch work to another server as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to "bypass" WCF service, submitting all the requests at once and than start each workflow but it is the same, I think I have to create a queue and start just some instances at time. Is there an efficent known way yo do that?